# Swift - Getting around build errors in test-driven development?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, swift, tdd

I'm starting to learn how to do test-driven development, and I'm working with Swift. I'm suppose to have a test which should fail then write the code needed to get it to pass. From my understanding the test should successfully run, just fail. However, in Swift, when I try to write a test that, say, checks the value of a object's specific attribute, if that class doesn't yet have such an attribute (because I'm suppose to write the test first before I create it for that class) I don't get a failing test, but instead a build error when attempting to build and run the test. The error is that the test is trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist for the given object. Am I going about this the wrong way? Or are these test build breaking errors suppose to be what I get when doing TDD in Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDD is a great idea, but don't forget to apply some common sense. In a case like this, treat the build error as if it was a test failure. At some point you have to create the class and the attribute to get the code to build. Then, elaborate on your test to make it do something that fails, write the code that makes it pass, and continue.

Answer (score 5):

According to Uncle Bob's [3 Rules of Tdd](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd):

> 2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; **and compilation failures are failures**.

(emphasis mine).  So there is actually no need for "the test to successfully run" - compilation error is a fine excuse to write code :)

Comment: I am so glad you quoted Uncle Bob! I remembered him saying that in one of his talks, but I couldn't find it. You're absolutely right, compile errors are treated as test failures. I am writing a testing series in Swift using Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture on my new blog http://clean-swift.com. You may find it useful.